# MSSQL - Remove all text after a '-' in a varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I have a field in one of my tables that has names in it such as:
Category1 - Label1,
Category2 - Label2,
Category3 - Label3 and so on.

I created another field and I want to do an UPDATE that will copy all values over to the new field but so they appear as:
Category1
Category2
Category3

This would mean removing everything from the space before the hyphen to the right.

Note: There will ever only be one hyphen in the string to separate Category from Label.

Comment: What did you tried ? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx this will get you started

Comment: Is this a one off exercise or something that should continue to work for new rows and/or the existing column being updated with new category data? If the latter, you might want to consider a computed column rather than *manually* maintaining this second column.

Comment: which sql server version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update your_table
set col_new = case when charindex('-', col) > 0 
                   then RTRIM(left(col, charindex('-', col) - 1))
                   else col
              end
```

Comment: I think `LEFT` is preferable.

Comment: I agree I would have used a Left. Also Trim won't work in SQL Server you need RTRIM

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you have to select sub-string from Left using `CHARINDEX()` and `LEFT()` sql function. Then set Update new value in new column

```
UPDATE tblName
SET updatedColumn = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-', columnName) > 0 THEN
                         RTRIM(LEFT(columnName, CHARINDEX('-', columnName)-1))
                    ELSE columnName
                    END
```